# SSRS ExecutionLog no record in Catalog

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to analyse report usage in our Sql Server Reporting Services instance.

This worked fine:

> SELECT c.Name,el.UserName,el.TimeStart
>
> FROM ExecutionLog el
>
> INNER JOIN CATALOG c ON EL.reportid = c.itemid

But I then realised there were several records in ExecutionLog which did not have entries in CATALOG:

> SELECT c.Name,el.UserName,el.TimeStart
>
> FROM ExecutionLog el
>
> LEFT JOIN CATALOG c ON EL.reportid = c.itemid
>
> WHERE c.Path IS NULL

I assume this is due to reports being updated/deleted. Is there anyway to retain Catalog items.
I could create a nightly job to save Catalog info, but that seems a bit overkill

Comment: Unfortunately you have to create a secondary Catalog table and update it from the original (Use INSERT INTO ... WHEN NOT EXISTS) as reports can be deleted as you mentioned

Comment: ok, thats fine, just didn't want to go ahead with that if there was a less intrusive option. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The default retention period for that history data is 60 days.

You need to set the `ExecutionLogDaysKept` property to -1 so the ExecutionLog data will not "expire".

You can read and learn more about the **EnableExecutionLogging** and **ExecutionLogDaysKept** topics here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/server-properties-advanced-page-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017